# Find unique values of a cell vector without sorting the result

Tags: matlab, vector, cell

I have a vector of strings

```
          x = {'rrr' 'aaa' 'bbb' 'hhh' 'aaa' 'ppp'};
          y = unique(x);
```

This code returns unique value, but sorts them. Output of this code is

```
          y = {'aaa' 'bbb' 'hhh' 'ppp' 'rrr'}
```

I want it top return unique values, but unsorted. The output I want is

```
          y =  {'rrr' 'aaa' 'bbb' 'hhh' 'ppp'}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the second output argument of `unique`, which returns the index of the unique elements. To display them in the original order, use the `sort` function on the index vector before indexing the original vector.

```
 x = {'rrr' 'aaa' 'bbb' 'hhh' 'aaa' 'ppp'};
 [y,i] = unique(x);

 x(sort(i))
```

The output:

```
ans = 

    'rrr'    'bbb'    'hhh'    'aaa'    'ppp'
```

Answer (score 3):

[This blog entry explains it very well:](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/11/26/unique-values-without-rearrangement/)

```
    [X, SortVec] = sort(x);
    %Remove duplicates
    UV(SortVec) = ([1; diff(X)] ~= 0);
    %Resort to be back in original order
    y = B(UV);
```

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of MATLAB, R2012a, has additional options for the `unique` command that do [exactly what you need](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bs8f84v-1.html#btah2bc). For older versions, @HMuster and @Dan have good answers.